# Odoo 10 - Integrate third party JS libraries

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm trying to add a third party library into the Odoo system, I'm using Odoo 10.

The library I would like to integrate is this: https://github.com/ipluser/jquery-shifter but, I can't achieve that.

I simply coded the list on the view and called the library function *'shifter'*. But it does not work.

Here's my code.

```
odoo.define('crm_broadband.shifter', function(require){
'use strict'

$(function() {
    $('.shifter').shifter({
        maxShift: 1,
        switcher: true,
        responsive: true,
        speed: 1000,
    });
})
```

})

```
<div class="shifter-wrap">

                 <ul class="shifter">
                        <li>
                            <button class="oe_stat_button oe_broadband_btn" name="open_create_popup"
                                    icon="fa-plus" type="object"
                                    attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_id', '!=', False)]}"
                                    sequence="0">
                                <field string="Broadband" name="name" widget="statinfo"/>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="shifter-forward" href="javascript:void(0)">forward</a>
                    <a class="shifter-backward" href="javascript:void(0)">backward</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: have you installed it correcty and included the necessary file from on your head section?

Comment: Yes, I don't think the installation installation is the problem. I tried it in a standalone HTML and it works fine.
I tried to put the inclusions in both *'assets_backend'* and *'assets_frontend'* but nothing, even though the js file is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Actually the problem was that the $('.shifter') could not find the element.
Solved using  *'this.$el.find('.shifter')'* inside the *'start'* function of the *'web.FormView'*.

Now appears another problem..

As soon as the *'ul.shifter'* ends the wrapper space it let its element go to a new line, canceling the script functionality.
Also, if I don't set the width of the *'ul'* element, the script can't set it on its own, making it of 0px width.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

```
instance.web.FormView.include({

    start: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)

        // WRAP CHILDREN IN 'li > ul > div'
        this.$el.find('.oe_button_box')
            .children()
            .wrapAll("<div class='shifter_wrap'></div>")
            .wrapAll("<ul class='shifter'></ul>")
            .wrap("<li class='shifter_element'></li>")

        this.$el.find('.shifter').shifter()
    },
})


.shifter-wrap {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  height: 40px !important;
}
.shifter {
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  max-width: @sheet-max-width !important;
  min-width: 132px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
.shifter_element {
  width: 132px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left !important;
}
```

### EDIT END

---

Ok, solved.
I called my script inside a <*head*> declared in the view I was extending, instead of the *'assets'* template in the start of the file.

```
<record id="crm_case_form_view_oppor_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.form.opportunity.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//div[@name='button_box']/button[1]" position="before">

                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                    <meta name="renderer" content="webkit"/>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/crm_broadband/static/src/js/shifter.js"/>
                </head>


                <div class="shifter-wrap">
                    <ul class="shifter">
                        <li>
                            <button class="oe_stat_button oe_broadband_btn" name="open_create_popup"
                                    icon="fa-plus" type="object"
                                    attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_id', '!=', False)]}"
                                    sequence="0">
                                <field string="Broadband" name="name" widget="statinfo"/>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </xpath>
       </field>
</record>
```

Comment: if it is possible, can you share me the full code (vigneshkrmmc@gmail.com)